# From size (1000,9) and (1000,10) matrix to matrix of size (1000,90)

Tags: tensorflow, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I have two matrices:
- A (1000,9)
- B (1000,10)

Now A[0,0] should be multiplied by B[0,0], B[0,1], ... B[0,9]

A[0,1] should be multiplied by B[0,0], B[0,1], ... B[0,9]

A[1,0] should be multiplied by B[1,0], B[1,1], ... B[1,9]

etc

Such that the resulting matrix has size (1000,90)

Is this possible in Tensorflow with only matrix operations, without loops?
By some broadcasting rules I think it should be possible, but I don't have the answer yet.

tf.tile could be a solution to tile both Tensors to the (1000,90) shape and then do a elementwise multiplication. But maybe there are nicer solutions

Comment: I think reshape is the operation I am looking for to reshape the first tensor to a 1-D tensor. Then broadcasting can be applied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
C = A[:, tf.newaxis, :] * B[:, :, tf.newaxis]
```

This gives us a [1000, 10, 9] tensor where element [i, j, k] is A[i, k] * B[i, j]. Then we reshape

```
C = tf.reshape(C, [tf.shape(A)[0], -1])
```

to [1000, 90]. If I'm not mistaken, each row i of C will first have B[i, 0] multiplied by all elements in A[i], then B[i, 1] multiplied by all elements of A[i] etc (you might want to double check this). If you want it the other way around you can swap the `tf.newaxis` around in the first part.